Kotlin Multiplatform Library - Best practices for library dependencies
I'm creating a Kotlin Multiplatform library that interacts with a Restful HTTP API service. The library depends on Ktor and Kotlin Serialization. When importing the library, users also have to import these dependencies.

What are the best practices when using dependencies on libraries?
What can I do to facilitate library installation for the developer?
Is there a way to avoid using dependencies when creating a library that needs a HTTP client?

Thank you!

I would guess you need to make ktor, etc, "api" dependencies rather than "implementation"?


Ktor provides good docs for multiplatform app

Follow the docs ^^^, update gradle/libs.versions.toml, and add the source set dependencies. Gradle will take care of pulling down the deps, and they will become part of the app package during final app deploy build task.

For functionality like a HTTP client the only options I know of are pulling in a dependency like ktor, or writing the HTTP client yourself.


